# fancybox 2 and form with response in same page

Tags: forms, fancybox

I'd like to use Fancybox 2 with jQuery to open a page via Ajax, form_page.php and then get the response in the same fancybox window...

I use this as js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 550,
        maxHeight   : 450,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

html is:

```
<a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="/form_page.php">Ajax</a>
```

I just need that the POST is loaded in the same /form_page.php inside Fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

I use the iframe variation when putting forms in Fancybox.  This allows me to do regular posts, etc.  When the form is successfully processed, I use JavaScript to close the Fancybox "pop-up" and refresh the calling parent document.

**Fancybox "Pop-up" Forms:**

```
$('a.popup').fancybox({
    'type':'iframe',
    'hideOnContentClick':false,
    'overlayShow':true,
    'speedIn':100,
    'speedOut':50,
    'width':600,
    'height':500,
    'padding':0,
    'margin':0,
    'onClosed':function(){window.location.reload();},
    'onComplete':function(){$('input.focus:last').focus();}
});
```

**Close "Pop-up":**

```
if (window.self !== window.top) {
    // is nested
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you have some example code of forms you have used fancybox with?  I've been working on fancybox popup forms and getting them to validate is causing me trouble.  The fancybox 1 FAQ page has an example, but I'm using fancybox 2 for site-wide popups...

Comment: I am using Fancybox 1.3.4. Fancybox 2 has different licensing, and I haven't gotten the go-ahead to make the purchase

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to declare your fancybox and use the option afterShow to bind your form:

```
    $('.various').fancybox({
        closeClick: false,
        afterShow:  function() {
            $("form#user_new").bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
                // When your form will be submitted and successfull,
                // You can try to open a fancybox here with your result here
            }
        }
    });
```

That's not really a code to copy/paste because I didn't give exactly what you want, for the simple reason that I don't know as well ;) but if it can help.